# How to move working docker project from windows environment to ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, nginx

Im now in process of moving running laravel webapp to docker containers and then setting it up in ubuntu server for temporary use. I have access to all files in webapp folder and database. So far i have moved webapp to docker in windows. Wrote dockerfiles for laravel and mysql, docker-compose.yml and also some cronjobs are implemented in dockerfile and seperate script.sh file.

Now i can in windows powershell do *docker-compose build* and then *docker-compose up -d* and webapp is working on my local system, i can login acces database data etc.. Everything works same as public webapp.

So part i am struggling a lot is moving those 4 images(laravel,nginx,mysql,redis) to ubuntu server and and running them. i did push and pull images to and from repository. I managed to run on custom port nginx container but it shows blank Welcome to nginx page. So how can i move this project? How i can tell docker on ubuntu to cominucate with other images? Do i need to move also all webapp files? Dosent make sense to me because then whats the point of dockerizing whole project.

Comment: I'd expect you should be able to check out your source repository on the new system and run `docker-compose up --build` and it should work, less any content that was in the original database.  Just to get the application running from source you shouldn't need to do anything Docker-specific.

Comment: This is what i was trying to avoid or do with out this, because it require moving also Dockerfile and i guess ill have to move my script.sh So just clean run is not possible? 

Also i did move docker-compose.yml and dockerfiles to temporary ubuntu machine and now im facing this error when doing docker-compose up

Dial TCP lookup registry-1.docker.io temporary failure in name resolution....... this is frustrating..

Comment: OK. i didnt have to move Dockerfiles. When i moved images i renamed them, so docker-compose was trying to rebuild them.  All i needed is docker-compose file. So far so good but now when i start i am getting 404 error :))))

Answer (score 0):

If everything is setup correctly, only needed files are containers, docker-compose.yml and config files if those are used in docker-compose.yml.